# Add new field to index.json in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to add a modified variable to my index.json.

**views/posts/index.json.builder**

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  post[:image_th] = post[:image].reverse.split('.', 2).join(".s").reverse
  #this is the new line above

  json.extract! post, :id, :title, :datum, :body, :image
  #json.url post_url(post, format: :json)
end
```

So itt adds an 's' before ".jpg" in the string.

This gives error:

> can't write unknown attribute `image_th'

How to add a field to index.json without creating a migration and accessing it from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def image_th
    image.reverse.split('.', 2).join(".s").reverse
  end

end
```

And then:

```
json.extract! post, :id, :title, :datum, :body, :image_th
```

EDIT:

Also the method would be probably slightly cleaner with:

```
def image_th
  image.sub(/\.[^\.]+$/, 's\0')
end
```

Comment: Why didn't I think about that? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to persist it, you can use an `attr_accessor :image_th` in your `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::base
  attr_accessor :image_th
end
```

Anyway that claims more to be a method than a field in your model

Comment: This is rails4, no attr_accessor there.